# confirmDeveiceCredentialIntent from non-activity/application context

Tags: android, android-keystore

As we know, we have an api in `KeyguardManager` for authenticatng the user through his device lock. The api is : [confirmDeviceCredentialIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).
The doc for this api says :

> Get an intent to prompt the user to confirm credentials (pin, pattern or password) for the current user of the device. The caller is expected to launch this activity using startActivityForResult(Intent, int) and check for RESULT_OK if the user successfully completes the challenge.

Now, my problem is, I want to invoke this flow in a non-activity context. I am using a kv store in my app whose contents would be encrypted by the key that I am storing in android keystore. So when I want to get any value fro that store, I first need to authenticate user so that I get my key and decrypt the content before returning.

Second thing is, I, as a consumer of that kv store, don't want to be aware about how the encryption of the store is done and therefore I shouldn't invoke confirm credentials myself. I just want my value from the store and it's store's (which is non-ui component) responsibility to invoke the authentication flow if it's required.

So mostly, I'd be using the global application context. And this context doesn't provide `startActivityForResult` api.

Is there any other way by which I can get result of confirm credentials action from user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Dummy Activity. This activity itself is launched by application context and then it handles invoking `confirmCredentials` intent for result.